# How to use Dask DataFrame with Numpy Busday_count?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask, dask-dataframe

I am working to convert Pandas/Numpy code to Dask for handling of larger datasets. I cannot seem to re-create the following Pandas/Numpy code:

```
df['days_to_complete'] = np.busday_count(begindates=df['time_order_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),enddates=df['time_complete_date'],weekmask='1111111',holidays=hols_list)
```

This returns an integer number of days between the time_order_date and time_complete_date while considering a work week and holiday list. It creates and populates a new column in my dataframe, no problems.

### In Dask, I have tried the following:

1. map_partitions calling the numpy function:

   `ddf['days_to_complete'] = ddf.time_order.map_partitions(func=np.busday_count,args= ddf['time_order_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),ddf['time_complete_date']),meta=(None, 'i8'))`
2. Also map_partitions using lambda:

   `ddf['days_to_complete'] = ddf.map_partitions(lambda ddf: ddf.assign(result = np.busday_count(begindates=ddf['time_order_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),enddates=ddf['time_complete_date'],weekmask='1111111',holidays=hols_list)),meta=(None,'i8'))`

and get the following error after running ddf.compute():

```
TypeError: busday_count() got multiple values for argument 'begindates'
```

**How do you best use this numpy function in a parallel processing / Dask friendly way?**
I have not been successful using the Dask docs/examples or other SO threads.
I'd like to also use a Pandas CustomBusinessHour rollfoward like I have working in basic pandas here:

```
bis_hour = CustomBusinessHour(n=1,weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun',holidays=hols_list,start = bus_hours_start,end = bus_hours_end,offset=0)
df['time_order_bis'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_order'])
df['time_order_bis'] = df['time_order_bis'].apply(lambda row: bis_hour.rollforward(row))
```

This 'rolls forward' the order time to be within the defined customer business hours (Saturday order now is 7am Monday, a working day). Thanks!

**Edit:**
I have tried writing and calling a function:

```
def bdays(df):
  return np.busday_count(df.time_order_date.values.astype('datetime64[D]'),df.time_complete_date,weekmask='1111111',holidays=hols_list)
ddf['days_to_complete'] = ddf.map_partitions(bdays,df=ddf,meta=('days_to_complete','i8')).compute()
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: bdays() got multiple values for argument 'df'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! The key was to return a Dask array and not compute things too soon, which breaks the types. I recommend doing lots of type() checks and go step by step, you want Dask objects all along the way essentially, pandas objects/numpy arrays can break the partitioning/parallelism.

Function:

```
def bdays(df=ddf):


return da.from_array(np.busday_count(df.time_order_date,df.time_complete_date,weekmask='1111111',holidays=hols_list))
```

Use map_partitions. Please note the first parameter of the function above requires the dataframe/partition -> we do not specify this in map partitions! Only additional parameters.

```
ddf['days_to_complete'] = ddf.map_partitions(bdays,meta=('days_to_complete','i8'))
```

Computing (compute()) before the assignment to the new column in my dataframe caused errors.

```
TypeError: set_index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

Debugging suggestion:
Test your inputs and test the function with only one partition. bdays is the function from above.

```
type(ddf.map_partitions(bdays,meta='i8'))
```

`output: dask.dataframe.core.Series`